# Return date in the format "<ordinal> <dayname> of the month" php

Tags: php

Using strtotime its easy to return the nth day of a given month, using `strtotime` e.g.

```
date("j, d-M-Y", strtotime("second wednesday 2018-10"));
```

Is there a way of doing the reverse? For example, if I were to check today's date (Tuesday 2nd Oct 2018). I'd like to get back 'first Tuesday of the month'.

Comment: *quickly searches the PHP manual for the `emitotrts()` function

Comment: last comment cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a PHP library that can do what your question asks. I've had a go at writing a function that does what I think you want, and you can modify the returned string to get your desired output.

But here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/37BRW

```
function dateToOrdinalString($date) {
    // Convert datestring to timestamp, and prepare day, month, and year names
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode(' ', date('l F Y', $timestamp));

    // Prepare ordinals
    $ordinals = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

    // Iterate through ordinal values
    foreach ($ordinals as $ordinal) {
        $string = "{$ordinal} {$day} of {$month} {$year}";

        // Compare original and ordinal timestamp for equality
        if ($timestamp === strtotime($string)) return $string;
    }

    return false;
}

echo dateToOrdinalString('2018-12-25');
// fourth Tuesday of December 2018
```